# Is it possible to let my static framework access iOS application folders? [iOS]

Tags: ios, static-libraries, dynamic-library

Currently I am developing an SDK and it is best to be designed as a static framework. It shall access some network-downloaded resource files located in the application folder, like /var/mobile/Applications/... I tried to pass the absolute file path and it can not get the resource. Then I rebuild the SDK into a dynamic framework (with Embed&Sign in Xcode-General), it can access the application folder with no problem.

Are there anyways to make static framework have access to application folder?

Answer (score 0):

On the iOS platform of a real device, you cannot use the absolute path to access network-downloaded resource files located in the application folder because of the sandbox file system. instead, you can use   [`NSDocumentDirectory` API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssearchpathdirectory/nsdocumentdirectory)  to access them. Before you access the file, you had better use [`fileExistsAtPath` API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1415645-fileexistsatpath)  to check if the file exists at the path.

If you are confused, you can use the framework named  [FLEX](https://github.com/FLEXTool/FLEX)  to confirm if the file is downloaded successfully.

Comment: I am using NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); to get application support directory. 

In fact the path I got is /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DD42D5DE-E18C-47A7-BE4A-92EE8E9718FB/Library/Application Support/...

Since Dynamic Framework can access the files using this path, I am wondering if it is not the problem of this path.

Comment: Before you access the file, you had better use [`fileExistsAtPath` API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1415645-fileexistsatpath "`fileExistsAtPath` API")  to check if the file exists at the path.

If you are confused, you can use the framework named  [FLEX](https://github.com/FLEXTool/FLEX "FLEX")  to confirm if the file is downloaded successfully. @MortyXiong